# Only display highest value

Tags: java, sql, arrays

I want this function to display the highest value and the index in the array.If the index is the highest, it will retrieve all the value in sql. But when I run this program, it displays a lot of values...How to solve it?

```
  private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray(); 
                 double highest=aa[0]; 
                 System.out.println(highest); // display value in aa[0]
                  for(int i=1;i<aa.length;i++)
                 {
                     if(aa[i]>highest)
                     {
                         highest=aa[i];

                         System.out.println(highest); //print the highest value only
                         System.out.println(i);

                         String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =?";
                         DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                         Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                         PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                         ps.setDouble(1, i+1); 
                         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                         if (rs.next()) 
                         {  
                          String aaa=rs.getString("place1");  
                          String bbb=rs.getString("place2");
                          String cc=rs.getString("place3");
                          String dd=rs.getString("place4");
                          String ee=rs.getString("place5");
                          String ff=rs.getString("place6");
                          String gg=rs.getString("place7");
                          String hh=rs.getString("place8");
                          String iii=rs.getString("place9");
                          String jj=rs.getString("place10");
                          String kk=rs.getString("place11");
                          String ll=rs.getString("place12");
                          String mm=rs.getString("place13");
                          String nn=rs.getString("place14");
                          String oo=rs.getString("place15");
                          String pp=rs.getString("budget");
                          Tourism to =new Tourism();
                          to.setPlace1(aaa);
                          to.setPlace2(bbb);
                          to.setPlace3(cc);
                          to.setPlace4(dd);
                          to.setPlace5(ee);
                          to.setPlace6(ff);
                          to.setPlace7(gg);
                          to.setPlace8(hh);
                          to.setPlace9(iii);
                          to.setPlace10(jj);
                          to.setPlace11(kk);
                          to.setPlace12(ll);
                          to.setPlace13(mm);
                          to.setPlace14(nn);
                          to.setPlace15(oo);
                          to.setBudget(pp);
                          DispDay dc=new DispDay();
                          dc.setVisible(true);
                         }
                         ps.close();
                         rs.close();
                         conn.close();

                 }
                     else if(highest==aa[0])
                     {
                         String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =1";
                         DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                         Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                         PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                         if (rs.next()) 
                         {  
                          String aaa=rs.getString("place1");  
                          String bbb=rs.getString("place2");
                          String cc=rs.getString("place3");
                          String dd=rs.getString("place4");
                          String ee=rs.getString("place5");
                          String ff=rs.getString("place6");
                          String gg=rs.getString("place7");
                          String hh=rs.getString("place8");
                          String iii=rs.getString("place9");
                          String jj=rs.getString("place10");
                          String kk=rs.getString("place11");
                          String ll=rs.getString("place12");
                          String mm=rs.getString("place13");
                          String nn=rs.getString("place14");
                          String oo=rs.getString("place15");
                         String pp=rs.getString("budget");
                          Tourism to =new Tourism();
                          to.setPlace1(aaa);
                          to.setPlace2(bbb);
                          to.setPlace3(cc);
                          to.setPlace4(dd);
                          to.setPlace5(ee);
                          to.setPlace6(ff);
                          to.setPlace7(gg);
                          to.setPlace8(hh);
                          to.setPlace9(iii);
                          to.setPlace10(jj);
                          to.setPlace11(kk);
                          to.setPlace12(ll);
                          to.setPlace13(mm);
                          to.setPlace14(nn);
                          to.setPlace15(oo);
                          to.setBudget(pp);
                          DispDay dc=new DispDay();
                          dc.setVisible(true);
                         }
                         ps.close();
                         rs.close();
                         conn.close();
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: Sort the array, pick the last element, there's your highest value.  Do away with the `for-loop`, basically anytime `aa[i]` is greater then `highest`, it grabs the results from the database, but if your array contains something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, you'll be getting EVERY record

Comment: I using the cosine similarity and the value of each row is unknown..

Comment: Then you need to determine the highest value FIRST, before trying to load the results from the database.  You could define your own `Comparator` to provide a custom sorting based on your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use `MAX`

**Please** change your approach, and use the SQL [`MAX` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php). Something like,

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM placeseen WHERE budget = ("
    + "SELECT MAX(budget) FROM placeseen)";
```

You could then use something like

```
int id = rs.getInt("id");
float budget = rs.getFloat("budget");
```

And I would recommend limiting the columns (if you only want the two) like

```
String sql = "SELECT id, budget FROM placeseen WHERE budget = ("
    + "SELECT MAX(budget) FROM placeseen)";
```

Comment: I using cosine similarity to compare the similarity between each row in the sql, the MAX function might not used

Comment: Well, `ps.setDouble(1, i+1);` is a bit unsettling in your code then. Since `i` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `for (int i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++)`?
Store `array[i]` in a variable, and the actual `int` found in that index in another variable. Then, when you loop through it more: `if (array[i] > biggestInt)`, store the new index number and new biggest integer in their appropriate variables.